# Clone a git project from window to mac

Tags: git, macos, window

I want to clone a git project from window to mac.

I type the following command on my macbook:

```
git clone //<window-1-name>/Projects/<window-1-folder-path>
```

return a message:

fatal: repository '//<window-1-name>/Projects/<window-1-folder-path>' does not exist

What I've tried:

change computer name to ip-address, still fail.

But I use another notebook window-2 and I can clone the projects.

So I don't know whether we can clone a git project from window to mac using this method.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I guess it's a OS/FS thing. If you do `ls -l //<window-1-name>/Projects/<window-1-folder-path>`, what do you see?

Comment: You need a protocol like ssh:, http: or https: to access the distant repository. Or are you sharing a directory?

Comment: Yes, I am sharing a directory from window-1, so I can clone the project from window -1 to window-2, but it fails from window-1 to mac @Jean-BaptisteYunès

Comment: I see the message 'No such file or directory' @eftshift0

Comment: How can you list the _repo_ using `ls`? As long as you are not able to solve that, git won't be able to do anything (at least with `file://` as a transport).

Comment: I don't think you can access a window share just like that. If you have Finder running, you can automatically mount the windows share into your file system using `open 'smb://<username>:<password>@<window-1-name>/Projects/<window-1-folder-path>'` Then look into `/Volumes/` for a folder similar names to the share folder. Use that folder as source in your git clone command.
Alternative approach is mounting manually: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/699 (There is also a apple script solution further below)

Comment: Thanks all for your help!! I've solved my problems.

Answer (score -1):

The commands I used on mac:

```
git clone /Volumes/<window-1-name>/Projects/<window-1-folder-path>
```

That path can be found using the 'mount' command.